# DBRE Spring Roo problem

Tags: postgresql, reverse-engineering, spring-roo

I'm trying to use Spring Roo for the first time to generate the code using the reverse engineering.

After installing the Postgresql addon by:

> osgi install --url  `http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release/org/springframework/roo/wrapping/org.springframework.roo.wrapping.postgresql-jdbc3/8.4.701.0001/org.springframework.roo.wrapping.postgresql-jdbc3-8.4.701.0001.jar`

I try the next command:

> database introspect --schema USER

I'm sure that i have the USER schema in my database (when i use the TAB key, i get USER with other shema names with the right case-sensitivity) but spring response was:

```
roo> database introspect --schema

USER                  information_schema    pg_catalog
pg_toast_temp_1       public
roo> database introspect --schema USER
Schema 'USER' does not exist or does not have any tables. Note that the schema names of some databases are case-sensitive
```

Answer (score 3):

I got to this question after having a similar problem and thought I would answer this even though the question is an year old.

My issue was that I had not included the database name in the database.url property. After adding it the database introspect started working.

```
database.url=jdbc\:postgresql\://localhost\:5432/<dbname>
```

Strange though that the tab completion works and shows options for the schema giving a false impression that all is well with the database configuration.